# Why is the context of this different in these two functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.newCategory = {
        name: ko.observable(''),
        canSubmit: function() {
            return this.name() !== '';
        },
        submit: function() {
            var data = 'name=' + this.name();
            $.post('/api/createcategory', data, function(res) {
                //...
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And the HTML

```
<button type="button" data-bind="enable: newCategory.canSubmit(), click: newCategory.submit">Create category</button>
```

In the `canSubmit()` function, `this` refers to `self.newCategory` as I'm expecting. However, for some reason in the `submit()` function, `this` refers to `ViewModel()` Why is this?

Comment: `this` refers to whatever the object is that the function is called on.  If it is the view model, then it seams the that data binding is taking a reference to the function and calling it on the view model somehow.

Comment: Right, but it seems like the context should be the same on both of those functions. I'm not really sure why it isn't. Something internal to the way knockout manages its bindings, I guess

Comment: The context _shouldn't_ be the same for those two functions. In the first case you call `canSubmit` _on_ `newCategory`. In the second case you pass the `submit` function to the `click` binding which knockout will call with whatever context it sees fit.

Comment: Tomalak's is definitely the cleanest and best practice, but I think a shorter answer might be "that's the point of using `self`" - in knockout, it's become very common to create `var self = this` at the beginning of your view model, so that you can always use `self.` when referring to the view model context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout calls functions in the context of the viewmodel that they are bound to, in your case the main viewmodel. Hint: The viewmodel for `submit` is not the object that you assigned to `newCategory`.

In your binding you do two different things:

- `enable: newCategory.canSubmit()` calls the function right-away, on `newCateory`. So that's what `this` is going to be inside the function.
- `click: newCategory.submit` *mentions* the function, i.e. knockout creates a click handler that will run in the context of the current viewmodel.

Note that `canSubmit` actually ought to be observable.

When you change the binding context, for example using the `with` binding, the behavior is like you would expect it.

```html
<!-- ko with: newCategory -->
<button data-bind="enable: canSubmit, click: submit">Create category</button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

For sub viewmodels I like to create actual stand-alone constructors:

```
function Category() {
    var self = this;

    self.busy = ko.observable(false);
    self.name = ko.observable('');
    self.canSubmit = ko.computed(function() {
        return !self.busy() && self.name() > '';
    });
}
Category.prototype.submit = function() {
    var self = this;

    if ( !self.canSubmit() ) return;

    self.busy(true);
    $.post('/api/createcategory', {
        name: this.name()
    }).done(function(res) {
        //...
    }).always(function() {
        self.busy(false);
    });
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.newCategory = new Category();
}
```

and

```html
<!-- ko with: newCategory -->
<input type="text" data-bind="name">
<button data-bind="enable: canSubmit, click: submit">Create category</button>
<img src="spinner.gif" data-bind="visible: busy">
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `with` binding. I like how clean this is, and it would work great with requirejs, which I also use.

Comment: @Jedediah I've edited some more info into the answer.